# What is the difference between a subnet mask and a netmask?

Tags: router, ip, subnet, netmask

Is there any logic in using two different names for determining host ID and net ID?

For example, if you type `print route` in a Command Prompt you get things with *netmask*, but the IPv4 settings seems to use *subnet mask*.

Is there any significant difference between the two terms?

Comment: It is just slang.

Comment: then why should microsoft use 2 names for it ?

Comment: Why do we call William, Bill or Billy? We like to, and in some case, just lazy. The proper term is subnet mask, but they others are just used a lot, probably netmask more though.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The difference is very, very slight.  9 times out of 10, they will mean the exact same thing.

However, the terms can have a *contextual* meaning in cases where we're discussing the subnetting of a given network.  In those cases, the two terms "network mask" and "sub-network mask" can have distinct meanings.  That is, if we make a distinction between a "network" and a "sub-network" then "the mask of a network" and "the mask of a sub-network" mean different things because of the context.  This distinction is a *relative* distinction.

For example, let's say you've been issued the `10.10.0.0/16` network (using [CIDR notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIDR_notation)).  Here, your "network mask" is `255.255.0.0`.  Let's say you need to separate this network into 4 smaller networks, each as large as they could possibly be.  In order to get 4 networks out of `10.10.0.0/16`, you need to borrow two bits (00, 01, 10, 11) from the host address and use them for the subnet addresses.  This will give you the following sub-networks:

```
10.10.0.0/18
10.10.64.0/18
10.10.128.0/18
10.10.192.0/18
```

Here, your "network mask" is still `255.255.0.0`, but each "subnet mask" is `255.255.192.0`.

But, as I said, it's completely a *relative* term based on context.  One could also talk about `255.255.192.0` being a "network mask" and then `255.255.0.0` being a "supernet mask" if in the same context we're talking about `10.10.0.0/16` being a supernet of, say, `10.10.64.0/18`.  It's all based on the context of what is being discussed.

Comment: I can bet you that this is one of the best answers I have read. Thank you.

Comment: Crystal clear explanation.Appreciation and thanks.

Answer (score 9):

The "Netmask", "subnet mask", or simply "mask" are all the same thing: A mask that tells software which IPs belong to that network an which don't.

Comment: @SpiXel: Darth Android is correct.  This is not really even up for debate.

Comment: @SpiXel: Dividing a network into smaller parts may consist of using VLANs to separate and/or isolate traffic, such as DMZs, servers, HR, Marketing, Developers, iSCSI, backups, etc.

Comment: @jftuga: yes that's right for the smaller networks part,Thank You :)