# What is major network mask and subnet mask

Tags: networking, ip, subnet, netmask

I've been served with a question to find `Major Network Mask` and I've only given `Host IP address` and `sub-net mask`. I have to find the Major Network Mask using Host IP and sub-net mask.

[Another stackoverflow question says both are the same](https://superuser.com/questions/315352/what-is-the-difference-between-a-subnet-mask-and-a-netmask)

I've attached screenshots of the question and the steps.

The step describes how to filter host and network information, but you need to find `Major Network mask` to **draw M.D. line**.

[image: Step describing drawing M.D line]

but in my question, I've only given Host IP and subnet mask.
[image]

Comment: I suspect this is classful addressing, so the major network mask would be `255.0.0.0` for `10.x.x.x`.

Comment: Thanks! Yes it is I just found the Network Mask Table, it depends on the class of the IP. http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk365/technologies_tech_note09186a00800a67f5.shtml

Comment: @Michael can you submit this as an answer outlining your findings?

Comment: @50-3 : Done! :)

Comment: @Michael Gamage Ugh. Classful IPs have no been used in decades. it is all CIRD now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Major Network Mask** is always assigned by the `class` of the IP addresses used on the network.

If a network has **Class A** `IP Addresses` assigned to hosts, **Major Network Mask** is `255.0.0.0`

**Class A**: `255.0.0.0`

**Class B**: `255.255.0.0`

**Class C**: `255.255.255.0`

In my case, IP address `10.210.188.56` is a **Class A** `IP address`,so the **Major Network Mask** is `255.0.0.0`